# Google sheets exclude rows from filterArray

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-query

I hope you can help me with an issue.

I have a code that is copying rows from 1 tab to the other based on the time in column 10. I got the code from here and have amended it to my needs. As part of this code I have a second tab with similar information from which it just needs to delete the same rows. However I receive an error message when it starts with the second tab and states "Cannot find function getTime in object...". I am guessing this is due to my title bar that does not have a time in column 10. Is there any way of excluding rows from the filterarray?

```
function moveRows() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var s = ss.getSheetByName("Today");
    var sr = ss.getSheetByName("Request History");
    var target = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
    var today = new Date().getTime()
    var val = filterArray(s.getDataRange()
        .getValues());
    for (var len = val.length - 1, i = len; i >= 3; i--) {
        if (val[i][10].getTime() < today) {
            target.appendRow(val[i])
            s.deleteRow(i + 1)
        }
    }
    var val = filterArray(sr.getDataRange()
        .getValues());
    for (var len = val.length - 1, i = len; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (val[i][10].getTime() < today) {
            sr.deleteRow(i + 1)
      }
    }
}

function filterArray(array) {
    var filteredArray = [];
    array.forEach(function (r) {
        if (r[10] !== '') {
            filteredArray.push(r);
        }
    });
    return filteredArray;

    var cell = s.getRange("A2:A2");
    cell.setFormula("=query('Request History'!A:F)");
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I am not a coder but usually manage to change code to fit my need when playing around with it.

Thanks,
Sjoerd

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to simply not have the script crash or delete the row when a date/time value is not present, you could "catch" the exception (error) you are receiving, in that case the script will simply move on to the next row after it receives this error.

This is simpler than changing "filterArray" to skip the header row for one tab but not the other.

```
for (var len = val.length - 1, i = len; i >= 0; i--) {
    try{
       if (val[i][10].getTime() < today) {
          sr.deleteRow(i + 1)
       }
     }catch(error){
        Logger.log('Caught an error processing item '+i+': '+error);
     }
}
```

See try/catch documentation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help! Please "accept" my answer so the question shows up as resolved